# Error in Xamarin when loading webpage with Qt Webassembly using Android WebView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview, webassembly

I have an Android 8.1 tablet and am trying to use the WebView in Xamarin to load up a bunch of Qt Web Assembly examples just to verify everything works. We are building a new product with Qt and would like to embed a WebViewer running a WebAssembly version of our new Qt application into our existing Xamarin application for Android. This should significantly accelerate development time.

I am having a bunch of problems with the WebView though and can't seem to narrow down whats going on. I enabled Javascript and allowed file and content access for the WebView but that did not fix things. I also went through the WebSettings and tried enabling pretty much everything which also didn't work. Lastly I downloaded the latest WebView onto the tablet and updated Google Chrome. On Xamarin itself I have updated every single dependency in Nuget to the latest version and that didn't fix anything.

NOTE ALL OF THE LINKS BELOW RUN PERFECTLY INSIDE THE CHROME BROWSER ON ANDROID 8.1!

This link when loaded in the WebView within the Xamarin application downloads, compiles, and appears to run just fine.

https://www.qt.io/web-assembly-example-gallery

[Qt web assembly example gallery](https://stackoverflow.com)

I just tested this example link and it works fine as well.

[Qt web assembly example slate](https://www.qt.io/web-assembly-example-slate)

These two links however give this error when loaded in the WebView.

**"Application exit (TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query'))"**

```
[chromium] [INFO:CONSOLE(352)] "exception thrown: TypeError: Cannot 
read properties of undefined (reading 'query'),TypeError: Cannot read 
properties of undefined (reading 'query')
[chromium]     at methodCaller_emscripten$$val_$emscripten$$val$ 
(eval at new_ (eval at completeLoadEmscriptenModule 
(https://www.qt.io/hubfs/_website/qt- 
webassembly/qtloader.js:409:14)), <anonymous>:5:20)
[chromium]     at __emval_call_method (eval at 
completeLoadEmscriptenModule (https://www.qt.io/hubfs/_website/qt- 
webassembly/qtloader.js:409:14), <anonymous>:1:138204)
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm-function[33830]:0xc22d3c
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm-function[33887]:0xc277ee
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm-function[30007]:0xaa7fc4
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm-function[38102]:0xd68e39
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm-function[36081]:0xca7016
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm-function[15582]:0x5eddc2
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm-function[32273]:0xbba2d9
[chromium]     at wasm://wasm/04fabb66:wasm- 
function[35983]:0xca4027", source: 
https://www.qt.io/hubfs/_website/qt-webassembly/qtloader.js (352)
```

[Qt web assembly example industrial panel](https://www.qt.io/web-assembly-example-industrial-panel)

[Qt web assembly example QML chart](https://www.qt.io/web-assembly-example-qml-chart)

This link also gives an error that is slightly different.

**"RangeError: Invalid typed array length: undefined"**

[Qt web assembly example pizza shop](https://www.qt.io/web-assembly-example-pizza-shop)

Any thoughts on what I could try next and any ideas what the real problem is / ways to fix it?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: I kept working on it and took our new Qt UI which is still pretty basic and I got it to build with Qt 6.5.0 into webassembly. It worked in Chrome on the computer but did not work in the WebView, just get a black screen. I found out that you can go into Chrome on the computer and remotely attach it to the WebView Chrome instance on the tablet. This helped me debug things. I got a new error "Uncaught RangeError: WebAssembly.Table.get() invalid index into function table qtloader.js:459:9". I have given up on the Webview and am now making our UI run natively on Android. The WebView is problematic.